# Sum all amount per user in Doctrine Group By Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get sum of each amount related to a user

this is my original code

```
public function getUserForThisTask($projectId)
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
      ->select('t.createdby','t.totalhour')
      ->where('t.project = :project_id')
      ->setParameter('project_id', $projectId);
      return $qb->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

This will return

```
  user     hours
  user1  = 20
  user2  = 30
  user1  = 3
  user1  = 4
```

Now I refactor by adding groupBy

```
  public function getUserForThisTask($projectId)
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
      ->select('t.createdby','t.totalhour')
      ->groupBy('t.createdby')
      ->where('t.project = :project_id')
      ->setParameter('project_id', $projectId);
      return $qb->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

Now this will be the result, as you see, some values related to user1 is not included

```
user    hours
user1  =  20
user2 =  30
```

Now I want this to total all hours related to each users

```
user    hours
user1 = 27
user2 = 30
```

How would you do thi?

Comment: I think you need `SUM(t.totalHour)` in the second query, otherwise it will just select the first of the group rather than totalling them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current query, as statedby @qooplmao, you have got only the virt `totalhour` of every group.

You need to sum all of them. So, your query must be something like:

```
  public function getUserForThisTask($projectId)
  {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.createdby','SUM(t.totalhour) AS TOTAL')
        ->groupBy('t.createdby')
        ->where('t.project = :project_id')
        ->setParameter('project_id', $projectId);
        return $qb->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
  }
```